# Identify this extremely tiny white bug please!

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I have noticed these extremely small, hard to notice with naked eye bug for about 3 nights now. Twice on my body in the kitchen and once on my thumb in my living room. I managed to catch one last night from my living room which has an area rug near a mattress, coffee table and couch. I managed to put it in a small 2 inch box with white lid. Today it seems little brownish and inspected it under a microscope.

First  picture is of the box size to put some real world perspective on the actual size.

[image]

Second pic is of the bug lying on the white lid, doesn't seem to be even 1.5 mm.

[image]

Third and fourth pic is from the microscope(150x), I had to move the bug so I might have squished it a bit.

[image]

[image]

We are getting bite marks and are almost convinced that this bug is the reason as we never had a bug problem ever. The only other thing we noticed is a silverfish in our living room but not sure if that can cause these bite marks.

Comment: Do you have birds or rodents in the home? Do you have birds nesting or spending a lot of time on any structure on the outside of your house?

Comment: Yes, we did have 2 bird nests in front of the main door on the roof, which we let since we didn't want to hurt the birds. But the birds left last week and we washed the nest afterwards on Monday10/5.

Comment: It appears to be a seed tick (tick larva). Have you visited a natural area or grassy area recently? As @theforestecologist seems to suggest, they could be from the birds that nested by your door.

Comment: Thanks @perfectionist. We have not been to any grassy area recently. We did however have 2 bird nest on the adjoining wall (with a window) under the roof which we let it be as we were not aware of consequences :)

Comment: @theforestecologist - I know you linked the thread which talks about Ornithonyssus. Just wanted to check if you think this is the same specie I am dealing with. This is to see if we can eliminate Red Mite /Dermanyssus Gallinae from the equation) and considering we are in USA, its highly likely we don't have Ornithonyssus Bursa (tropical fowl mite) so we might be able to zero in on Ornithonyssus sylviarum(northern fowl mite). We are infested for for about 4 months now and I am not sure how to devise an eradication plan since each type requires some specialized steps as I found in my research.

Comment: @Anx sorry to hear :/. You'll need to include better pictures if you want anyone online to help determine your species. If you've narrowed down to a few species as possibilities, see if you can find a resource or 2 that tell you what to pay attention to in order to differentiate them -- Using that info, take really clear zoomed-in pictures of body regions that are important for telling species apart. If you update your post asking to differentiate these species specifically, include a few more detailed photos and link to some useful info you found already, I'll reopen your post as unique.

Comment: Also, you might also consider contacting a local exterminator for help. If you're concerned about price, some will help ID a species before providing a quote... ...

Comment: @theforestecologist Appreciate you responding so quickly on this. We did reach out to a number of pest control operators (total 62 so far), but Orkin was the only one who came back with Bird Mite identification however they were not aware of specie level information. Also, we no longer have any visible mites in our environment, we were lucky to catch that first one. We have already gotten the pest control spray done 11 times by now, but these mites are so hard to beat :(  My last resort is to try fumigation but I am worried about the unhatched eggs..(as people reported) resulting it useless.